# Disable mondays and saturdays on jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need jQuery datepicker to disable an array of specific dates as well as all mondays and all saturdays. I have archieved the first two goals, but not the third one (disable saturdays). Here's the code:

```
let fechasEspecificas = ["2018-11-06"]

jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
  "minDate": 2,
  "maxDate": new Date(2019,0,31),
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      let string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      if (contains(fechasEspecificas,string)) {
        return [false, '']  // here are specific dates disabled
      } else {
        let day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1), '']; // here are mondays disabled
      }
    }
});


function contains(a, obj) {var i = a.length;while (i--) {if (a[i] === obj){return true;}}return false;}
```

[JSFIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6on7fsp/3/)

How could be the code extended in order to disable also saturdays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must concatenate the days that you will disable  with AND operation

```
let fechasEspecificas = ["2018-11-06"]

jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
    "minDate": 2,
  "maxDate": new Date(2019,0,31),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      let string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      if (contains(fechasEspecificas,string)) {
        return [false, '']
      } else {
        let day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1) && (day != 6), '']; //Add the day number 6 for disable saturdays as well
      }
    }
});


function contains(a, obj) {var i = a.length;while (i--) {if (a[i] === obj){return true;}}return false;}


jQuery('input').datepicker();
```

Comment: Thank you. Ill check in 8 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change `return [(day != 1), ''];` to `return [(day != 1 && day != 6), ''];`

Full Code:

```
let fechasEspecificas = ["2018-11-06"]

jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
    "minDate": 2,
  "maxDate": new Date(2019,0,31),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      let string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      if (contains(fechasEspecificas,string)) {
        return [false, '']
      } else {
        let day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 6), ''];
      }
    }
});


function contains(a, obj) {var i = a.length;while (i--) {if (a[i] === obj){return true;}}return false;}


jQuery('input').datepicker();
```

That will disable Monday and Saturdays.

Comment: Thank you. Ill have to check the first answer given